# c# Regex to match an HTML image tag if it does NOT have an http or https in the src

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a regex which is being used to parse some HTML and ensure that `img` tags have absolute references rather than relative.

This is the regex with the replace code:

```
string replaced;
var imgPattern = @"(?i)(<img.+?)(src=[\""'])(.+?)([\""'].*?>)"; //group 2 is the image path
replaced = Regex.Replace(Builder.ToString(), imgPattern, @"$1" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailAssetsURL"] + @"$2" + @"$3");
```

Now this works well (I know I don't really need 2 groups at the end) BUT I only want to do this IF the src does not already contain an absolute path ie contains http or https.

All help appreciated.

Comment: You need to proceed in two steps: 1) extract all src of img tags with an html parser, 2) check the begining of the link with regex or indexof

Comment: I would prefer not to use an HTML parser if it can be done with a Regex Pattern

Comment: Use a negative look-ahead: `(?!https?)`

Comment: If you us the literal input and expected output we should be able to point you in the right direction. Likely using negative look-ahead as @hjpotter92 noted

Comment: The negative look-ahead works perfectly thanks @hjpotter92. The pattern looks like this now: (?i)(<img.+?src=[\"'])(?!http:?)(?!https:?)(.+?)([\"'].*?>)

Comment: @MattWallis Replace `(?!http:?)(?!https:?)` with a single `(?!https?:)`

Comment: Thanks - I have already done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative look-ahead works perfectly thanks @hjpotter92. The pattern looks like this now:

```
(?i)(<img.+?src=[\"'])(?!http:?)(?!https:?)(.+?)([\"'].*?>)
```